# css animations end together even though they are started at different times

Tags: css, css-animations, delay

I have a few elements of the same type and I want them to share the same css animation, but I want them to start/end the animation at different times.

[Codepen for the following code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEZBaw)

The html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.box.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.box {
    animation: growIn 1s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.46,.13,.99,.83);
    transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.container:first-child .box {
    background-color: green;
}

.container:nth-child(2) .box {
    background-color: orange;
}

.container:nth-child(3) .box {
    background-color: red;
}

@keyframes growIn {
    from {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

The `box` elements start as hidden, and then using javascript I remove this classname from the different boxes but at different times:

```
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
boxes.forEach(box => {
    setTimeout(() => box.classList.remove("hidden"), Math.random() * 1000);
});
```

What happens is that all 3 boxes end their animation at the exact same time.  The animation does start at different times, but all end together.

Why is that?
If I do the same but add a classname instead of removing it (in order to make the animation start) then it behaves just as I want it to.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Because of `animation: growIn 1s;` they all take 1 second to make the same animation. The jQuery only controls when they start, but has no effect on the 1 second duration in your animation.

Comment: @SirExotic There's no `jQuery` involved here, and yeah they all have a 1sec animation duration but I'd expect that second to start when the animation start per item and not when the first one started.

Comment: Sorry, Javascript*. The Javascript code to "unhide" the boxes runs at the same time as your animation, so your animation is already starting even when it is still waiting for your Javascript to "unhide" a box. That's why you'll see some of the boxes appear with a size bigger than 0 already.

Comment: @SirExotic How is it that the animation for box 2 starts before the `hidden` classname was removed? Why does the animation of box 1 effect it? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: Change your animation duration to `5s` and as well as 5000 in your JS and you'll see it much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because all the animation have **already started at the same time**. Using `visibility:hidden` will not prevent the animation to start and make it start later when the element is visible. The same thing will happen with opacity for example:

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
boxes.forEach(box => {
  setTimeout(() => box.classList.remove("hidden"), Math.random() * 5000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box.hidden {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.box {
  animation: growIn 5s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.46, .13, .99, .83);
  transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.container:first-child .box {
  background-color: green;
}

.container:nth-child(2) .box {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container:nth-child(3) .box {
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes growIn {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
```

You can see the behavior you are looking for if you use the `display` property instead:

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
boxes.forEach(box => {
  setTimeout(() => box.classList.remove("hidden"), Math.random() * 3000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box.hidden {
  display:none;
}

.box {
  animation: growIn 1s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.46, .13, .99, .83);
  transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.container:first-child .box {
  background-color: green;
}

.container:nth-child(2) .box {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container:nth-child(3) .box {
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes growIn {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
```

---

From the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility):

> The 'visibility' property specifies whether the boxes generated by an
>   element **are rendered**.
>
> **Invisible boxes still affect layout** (set the
>   'display' property to 'none' to **suppress box generation altogether**).

So the box is **always** generated when using `visibility` unlike when using `display`.

And if we check the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/) related to the animation we will find this:

> Setting the display property to none will terminate any running
>   animation applied to the element and its descendants. If an element
>   has a display of none, updating display to a value other than none
>   **will start all animations applied to the element** by the animation-name
>   property, as well as all animations applied to descendants with
>   display other than none.

Comment: Thanks, changing to `display: none` did the trick. I was aware of the different between `visibility` and `display`, but I wasn't aware of the effect it had on the animation.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I also added the relevant part of the specification clearly explaining this behavior ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your box elements start with the .box class, which is the animation class. This means that the animation starts from the moment the elements are loaded, whether they are hidden or not. this means that when you remove the "hidden" class, they'll just reveal themselves at some point during the animation.

What you want to do is rename the animation class, for example "grower"

```
.grower {
    animation: growIn 1s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.46,.13,.99,.83);
    transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
```

Then have this in the javascript loop:

```
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
boxes.forEach(box => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    box.classList.remove("hidden");
    box.classList.add("grower"); }, Math.random() * 1000);
});
```

Here's a snippet to show it in action:

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
boxes.forEach(box => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    box.classList.remove("hidden");
    box.classList.add("grower"); }, Math.random() * 1000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.grower {
 animation: growIn 1s;
 animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.46,.13,.99,.83);
 transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.container:first-child .box {
  background-color: green;
}

.container:nth-child(2) .box {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container:nth-child(3) .box {
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes growIn {
  from {
  transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
  transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew that with adding a classname (i.e. `grower`) it can be done, but I wanted to avoid it as I'd later need to remove this classname when the animation ends because I don't need it anymore.